# Convex Combinations of Measures: $\mu_n \implies \mu$ implies $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \mu_x = \mu$ (weakly)?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Specifically, this is about Lemma 5.1 of A. M. Vershik's "Statistical mechanics of combinatorial partitions and their limit shapes," but I will ask my question in some generality.

Let $\mathcal{F}(x):= \sum_{n \geq 1} Q_n x^n$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $Q_n >0$.

Let $\{\mu_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{\mu_x\}_{x \in [0,1)}$ be, respectively, a discrete and continuous family of probability measures on the same space, where the $\mu_x$ are defined by $$\mu_x := \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1}\sum_{n \geq 1} x^n Q_n \mu_n.$$  This is called a *convex combination* because the coefficients sum to 1.

Vershik states that, because the $\mu_x$ are convex combinations, it is obvious that if the $\mu_n$ have a weak limit, then the $\mu_x$ have the same limit as $x \to 1^-$.

**Question:**  Why is the above true?

I can at least guess why it should maybe be true if we assume $\mathcal{F}(1)= \infty$, so $\mathcal{F}(1)^{-1}=0$ (which is the case for the $\mathcal{F}$'s in his paper).

Since $$\mu_x = \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1}\sum_{n = 1}^N x^n Q_n \mu_n+ \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1}\sum_{n > N} x^n Q_n \mu_n,$$ we have  $$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \mu_x = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1}\sum_{n > N} x^n Q_n \mu_n.$$  Now choosing $N$ so that the $\mu_n$'s are "close" to the weak limit $\mu$, the above is "roughly" $$\left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1}\sum_{n > N} x^n Q_n \right) \mu = \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \mathcal{F}(x)^{-1} \left(\mathcal{F}(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N x^nQ_n \right) \right) \mu = \mu.$$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track; you just need to apply the definition of weak convergence. You do need $\mathcal F(x)\to\infty.$

A sequence of probability measures $\nu_n$ converges weakly to $\nu$ iff for each bounded continuous $f$ and each $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N$ such that $|\int f d\nu_n-\int f d\nu|$ for $n>N.$ We can write this as: $\nu_n-\nu\in E$ for all sufficiently large $n,$ where $E$ is the set of finite signed measures $\tau$ with $|\int f d\tau|\leq\epsilon.$
Fix $f$ and $\epsilon$ and let $E$ be as I just defined.

We are given that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu.$ Applying the definition of weak convergence with $f$ and $\tfrac12\epsilon,$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\mu_n-\mu\in\tfrac12 E.$ In particular, $$\mathcal F(x)^{-1}\sum_{n>N}x^nQ_n(\mu_n-\mu)\in\tfrac12 E$$ because this is an infinitary convex combination of elements of the closed convex set $\tfrac12 E.$
Since $\mathcal F(x)\to\infty,$ as $x\to 1^-$ we have $$\mathcal F(x)^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N x^nQ_n(\mu_n-\mu) \in \tfrac 12 E$$
because each $Q_n(\mu_n-\mu)$ lies in $\tfrac{1}{2N}\mathcal F(x)E$ for sufficiently large $\mathcal F(x).$ Summing gives
$$\mu_x-\mu=\mathcal F(x)^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^nQ_n(\mu_n-\mu) \in E$$
which is the definition of $\mu_x$ converging weakly to $\mu.$

You might find it clearer to do everything in terms of real numbers - just replace $\mu_x,\mu_n,\mu$ by $\int f \mu_x$ etc, and replace $E$ by the interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon].$

Comment: Notice that you haven't used the continuity of $f$ anywhere; the same argument would have worked for the characteristic function of any measurable subset, which shows that one can obtain in fact *strong* convergence.

Comment: @AlexM.: that $B$ should have been an $f,$ thanks for noticing